# Moving an extended class from jar to application

Tags: java, class, interface, jar

I have an Interface and two classes as below. SkeletonInterface and SkeletonParent are auto generated. Currently all the three files resides in a jar file, which is deployed to a web project under web-inf/lib. I have a requirement to move the SkeletenChild from jar into web project.  I ran into issues when I tried that. How can I expose/access my implementation class in web project?

```
// auto generated interface
public interface SkeletonInterface{
    public int foo(int i){
    }
}

// auto generated class
public class SkeletenParent implements SkeletonInterface {
    public int foo(int i){
        // do not implement here 
    }
}

// Actual implementation class
public class SkeletenChild extends SkeletenParent{
    @override
    public int foo(int i){
        // want to implement here
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to reference the auto-generated code's JAR within the web project, and then import the code.

Comment: Thanks pickypg. I did that and built the web project and deployed it. The generated interface and class belong to axis2 web service, I embedded them in an web project.  I have a web service client app that calls the web project to invoke operations in SkeletenChild class. I am running into axis fault errors. There is no log activity on server side (web project) when I made a call from client side. I can tell from client app log that it is trying to invoke operations in SkeletenChild. If I move the SkeletenChild into jar on the server side app then everything works fine.

Comment: What's the actual error?

Comment: Issue resolved. I was not seeing the extended/child class during runtime because it was not deployed to server but the error I was getting was Axis fault, not sure why. I was hoping to see classnotfound exception. I use Tomcat 5.5 for development of this project and it seems clean deployment is not pushing the changes to server sometimes. I need to fix the build/deployment issues first! Thanks pickypg for your help.